# component function gets executed twice in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a component as follows:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app',
        template: `
<div>
    <div>value of a :
        <input [(ngModel)]="a" />
    </div>
    <div>value of b :
        <input [(ngModel)]="b" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Value of a = {{a}}
        <br> Value of b = {{b}}
        <br> Sum instantaneous {{calc(a+b)}}
    </div>
</div>
`   
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

        a: string = "";
        b: string = "";
        constructor() { }

        ngOnInit() {
        }

        calc() {
            console.log('test');
            return (+this.a + +this.b);
        }
    }
```

Every time, I modify (say, key press) anything in textboxes or even just focusing/defocusing textboxes, the 'calc' function gets executed twice.

What am I missing here or how can I get the function execute once (instead of twice).

Comment: Well, obviously when you modify some of the `inputs` with a model a or b, the function would be executed to change its value. but, I'm not sure if for that it has to execute also when it is in focus.

Comment: I am fine executing it once for any change.  In this case, it executes twice for every change.

Comment: in development mode angular runs two change detection cycles, meaning your calc function would be called twice. Try running 
ng serve --target -prod

ng help for ng serve
--target (String) (Default: development) Defines the build target.
    aliases: -t <value>, -dev (--target=development), -prod (--target=production), --target <value>

Comment: Will try that.  Thanks Derek

Comment: It worked.  Thanks @DerekKite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because change detection is run more often than you probably think, especially since you're in developer mode and everything gets checked twice.

You're not supposed to call functions from the template for exactly this reason. One of the solutions is to use pipes which can be declared as pure functions.

```
@Pipe({name: 'calc'})
export class CalcPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b
  }
}
```

And then use it like this.

```
{{ a | calc : b }}
```

Otherwise, you might want to write custom logic that will update a property in your class. Then just bind the property instead of the function call.